# Python CSV parsing and file generation

Tags: python, html, csv

I've got a CSV of over 500 entries and I'm trying to generate redirect files. The formatting of the CSV is:

```
/contact,/contact-us,
/about,/about-us,
```

The /contact is the **old** URL and the /contact-us is the **new** URL.

The formatting of the desired .htm file is:

```
url = "/contact"
is_hidden = 0
==
<?php
function onStart(){return Redirect::to("/contact-us");}
?>
==
```

The filename for the .htm files are unimportant (could be 1.htm, 2.htm, etc.).

I haven't really touched Python in several years and I'm not sure if it's the best option, but from what I've been reading, it seems like it's a solid choice for CSV parsing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
This is what I have so far

```
import pip
import csv
with open('redirects.csv') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
print 'url = "'+row[0]+'\nis_hidden = 0\n==\n\n<?php\nfunction onStart(){return Redirect::to("'+row[1]+'");}\n?>\n=='
```

This prints out exactly what I need. I just need to put  each entry into a .htm file (auto-incremented filename).

**Edit #2:
I got what I was looking for with this code:**

```
import pip
import csv
count = 0
with open('redirects.csv') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
count += 1
count_str = str(count)

file = open('redirects/'+count_str+'.htm', 'w')
file.write('url = "' + row[0] + '"\nis_hidden = 0\n==\n\n<?php\nfunction onStart(){return Redirect::to("' + row[1] + '");}\n?>\n==')
file.close()
```

Comment: Python or PHP??

Comment: @Nicarus Use Python to autogenerate PHP that creates url redirects from CSV sending users to a domain run on VB.net!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, something like below might work.

```
directories = open('filename', 'r').read()
splitted = directories.split(",")
correctlyformatted = [x.strip() for x in splitted]

counter = 0
for i in correctlyformatted:
    f=open(str(counter) + '.html', 'w')
    f.writeLines([
    'url = "' + i + '"',
    'i.s_hidden = 0',
    '==', 
    '<?php', 
    'function onStart(){return Redirect::to("' + i +'");}', 
    '?>', '=='])
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually completed it just a few minutes before I saw your post. Your code looks a heck of a lot cleaner than mine, so I'll mark it as the solution.